# How do you embed a variable into HTML within powershell?

Tags: html, powershell, csv, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I have an automated script which is importing users from a csv file into Active Directory.  I would like to send an email out for each user created with their username and password to the new users administrator for onboarding.  It's currently sending the email for each user but it's not embedding the username and password.

```
$newadstaff = Import-CSV "newad-staff.csv"
$mailpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'helpdeskpassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'helpdesk@google.com',$mailpwd
$googusr = $_.'HomePage'
$googpwd = $_.'AccountPassword'
$Body = @"
<style>
.colorchange {color:#4F81BD;}
ind {text-indent:50px;} 
</style>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div style="background-color:#3059D6; color:white; padding:20px;">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:40pt"; align=center><b>NEW STAFF USER ACCOUNT</b></p>
</div>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:20pt">A new Google account has been created for: </p>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt">Please navigate to <a href="https://google.com/accounts">Google Account Login</a> and login with the below credentials. You will be prompted to change your password after logging in:</p>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Username: $googusr </b>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Password: $googpwd </b>
</body>
</html>
"@

$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential  = $cred
From = 'helpdesk@google.com'
To = 'admin@google.com'
Subject = 'New User Account'
Body = $body

}
$When = ((Get-Date).Addhours(-1)).Date
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated | export-    csv "newad-staff.csv"

Foreach ($user in $newadstaff)
{
Send-MailMessage @param -BodyAsHtml
}
```

Comment: your user and pass variables have a value like you are defining it from a pipeline output. not sure if this is your whole script but I would probably `write-host` for each user and password variables and if they show up throw a `write-host` at the end of your body variable to make sure the text stream its creating includes the values you expect. Does the CSV you import a single account entry? if so then maybe your user and pass should have the format of `$newadstaff.AccountPassword` format.

Comment: The csv is a list of all users added to AD in the last hour.   I'm new to scripting/programming.  I'm still learning powershell so if you could provide examples and in the words of the great Michael Scott "Explain it to me like I'm 5." :)

Comment: created an answer version for you with a brief description. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is *how* and *where* you are declaring the variables

```
$googusr = $_.'HomePage'
$googpwd = $_.'AccountPassword'
```

`$_` is supposed to represent the current item in the pipeline. At the time of you assignment `$_` does not represent anything. You are assigning `$null` to both those values.

Your first line is for a CSV import `$newadstaff = Import-CSV "newad-staff.csv"`. Which seem odd since you later overwrite that file with the new users created in the last hour. In theory there is nothing wrong with that, it just seems odd. I left that order alone in the following code.

**New Code**

```
$newadstaff = Import-CSV "newad-staff.csv"
$mailpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'helpdeskpassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'helpdesk@google.com',$mailpwd
$Body = @"
<style>
.colorchange {{color:#4F81BD;}}
ind {{text-indent:50px;}} 
</style>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div style="background-color:#3059D6; color:white; padding:20px;">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:40pt"; align=center><b>NEW STAFF USER ACCOUNT</b></p>
</div>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:20pt">A new Google account has been created for: </p>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt">Please navigate to <a href="https://google.com/accounts">Google Account Login</a> and login with the below credentials. You will be prompted to change your password after logging in:</p>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Username: {0} </b>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Password: {1} </b>
</body>
</html>
"@

$param = @{
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Port = 587
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential  = $cred
    From = 'helpdesk@google.com'
    To = 'admin@google.com'
    Subject = 'New User Account'
    Body = ""
}

$When = ((Get-Date).Addhours(-1)).Date
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated | export-csv "newad-staff.csv"

Foreach ($user in $newadstaff)
{
    # The body of each mail is different. Set this body for the current $user
    $param.Body = $body -f $user.HomePage,$user.AccountPassword 

    Send-MailMessage @param -BodyAsHtml
}
```

You were never changing the body with the new information from each user. To make that easier I updated the here-string with some [`-Format`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) operator placeholders `{0}` and `{1}`. Now in the loop we update the body of `$param` and add the `HomePage` and `AccountPassword` in the same way you were trying with `$googusr` and `$googpwd`. `Send-MailMessage` stays the same.

**Note about the format operator**

Since you have curly braces in your `$body` string already they need to be escaped. Where you see `{` they get doubled up to `{{` and the same goes for the opposite brace. I did this to make the ForEach loop cleaner.

Comment: Matt, when I try this I get the following error:
Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
At line:39 char:5
+     $param.Body = $body -f $user.HomePage,$user.AccountPassword
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (<style>
Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty.
At line:41 char:22
+     Send-MailMessage @param -BodyAsHtml
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: GOt it... update coming. @Mike Try again for me with the whole code in the answer.

Comment: The above works :)  Thank you!  I would like to see if the other example can work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to structure your code like follows. Instead of defining your body one time at the top that gets addressed a single time when it parses from top to bottom you put it in your foreach loop creating a unique version for each mail message. You also need to have your CSV import variable after you do your AD User query Dump. (In reality you don't need to save it to CSV and re-import it as you would get the same object essentially if you simply did `$newadstaff = Get-AdUser ....`

Sorry I didn't test this at all but it looks about right.

```
$mailpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'helpdeskpassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'helpdesk@google.com',$mailpwd

$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential  = $cred
From = 'helpdesk@google.com'
To = 'admin@google.com'
Subject = 'New User Account'
Body = $body

}
$When = ((Get-Date).Addhours(-1)).Date

Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated | Export-Csv "newad-staff.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$newadstaff = Import-Csv "newad-staff.csv"

Foreach ($user in $newadstaff)
    {

    $Body = @"
    <style>
    .colorchange {color:#4F81BD;}
    ind {text-indent:50px;} 
    </style>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
    <div style="background-color:#3059D6; color:white; padding:20px;">
    <p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:40pt"; align=center><b>NEW STAFF USER ACCOUNT</b></p>
    </div>
    <p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:20pt">A new Google account has been created for: </p>
    <p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt">Please navigate to <a href="https://google.com/accounts">Google Account Login</a> and login with the below credentials. You will be prompted to change your password after logging in:</p>
    <p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Username: $($user.HomePage) </b>
    <p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><b>Password: $($user.AccountPassword) </b>
    </body>
    </html>
    "@

    Send-MailMessage @param -BodyAsHtml
    }
```

Comment: Ok this took care of the errors however in my test file I have 3 lines of users, this is sending 3 emails but all 3 have the first user info.  does the var need to be nulled?

Comment: First guess is that `@param` might not be updating with the changes to `$body`

Comment: yea my guess is what Matt is thinking as well, I can setup a test here in a bit and respond with a modified version above.

Comment: ha, didn't see Matt's solution, Brain dead at the moment. Glad its working.